# SQL Select Query between 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm having trouble on creating a query to pull data from 3 tables.

I have a `job_skus` table, `skus` table, and `stage` table, and I'm trying to select all the job skus for the whole month regardless of `jobNo`, for example to show a list of all job skus for the month of April.

The tables' structure is

```
Job_Sku                             example data
  JobNo                             J4454             J4454
  Sku (refences Product.Sku)        93339             9947
  Quantity                          500               600
  Stage                             1                 2

Products
   Sku(primary key)                 93339             9947
   Description                      Galvanised Nails  Steel Rods 900mm

Stage
 jobNo                              J4454             J4454
 stage                              1                 2
 date                               04/04/2015        12/04/2015
```

and so on.

I have come up with this query

```
SELECT jm.sku,jm.quantity,p.description 
FROM stage as s, products as p, job_sku as jm 
WHERE s.Date BETWEEN '2015-04-01' AND '2015-04-30' 
AND jm.stage = s.stage AND p.sku = jm.sku
```

but it seems to be  getting duplicate data in the query. Do I need to use a join of some sort, or maybe extract all the stages for that date period and join the result onto the `job_sku` table?

Comment: What is the purpose of `stage` in you query?

Comment: You're already doing joins, old style, implicit joins...

Comment: @Lennart, so im tracking materials, during a house build, so there are about 9-13 stages, so i use it to track the materials required for a certain job, and use the date field to gt a list of products that need to be ordered for a certain time frame

Comment: So there has to exist something in stage for a job (during a certain period of time). I'll do a sketch for that in a separate answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one suggestion. Others in the thread have suggested distinct that will result in the same thing, but using an exists predicate clarifies the intention of the query (IMO):

```
SELECT jm.sku
     , jm.quantity
     , p.description 
FROM  products as p
JOIN  job_sku as jm
    ON p.sku = jm.sku
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM stage s
    WHERE s.Date BETWEEN '2015-04-01' AND '2015-04-30' 
      AND jm.stage = s.stage
);
```

As others also have mentioned, ANSI joins will make the query a bit easier to understand. Vendors will continue to support the "," join for as long as we live, so the code wont break, but ANSI join will make it easier to maintain.

Comment: i just tried your query on my data, but im unsure how some data from april is showing up in a query that is looking in the month of "may" i have linked a picture http://i.imgur.com/Ba6hw23.png is it cause, its joining on p.sku and jm.sku and getting all skus

Comment: Not sure what you are saying here, only stage has a date and that is not exposed in the result. Are you saying that that job_sku that does not have a stage in may is returned?

Comment: yes that is correct, the result in the picture, is showing job_skus from April, that are showing up in May, so Skus 54115, for jobs 45545,45001 there respective stage dates are 2015-4-16 and 2015-4-29, i am unsure how it is showing up in Mays query, but all other months seem to work ok like Sku:78984 comes up in the June Query by it self.

Answer (score 5):

First, use proper joins. the join style you use is deprecated.
[Explicit joins](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) are a part of ANSI SQL for over 20 years now.

Second, if you get the correct results but some rows are duplicated, all you need to add is [`DISTINCT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html)

```
SELECT DISTINCT jm.sku,jm.quantity,p.description 
FROM stage as s 
INNER JOIN job_sku as jm ON(jm.stage = s.stage)
INNER JOIN products as p ON(p.sku = jm.sku)
WHERE s.Date BETWEEN '2015-04-01' AND '2015-04-30'
```

Comment: This is a much better answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT distinct jm.sku,jm.quantity,p.description 
FROM stage as s, products as p, job_sku as jm 
WHERE s.Date BETWEEN '2015-04-01' AND '2015-04-30' 
AND jm.stage = s.stage AND p.sku = jm.sku
```